# ClassNotFoundException after Changing Package Names in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, runtime-error, classnotfoundexception

I am working on a Java Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse.  Everything was running smoothly until I realized that my package names were uppercase, and decided to change them.

After changing them, I am getting ClassNotFoundExceptions at runtime.  The code compiles fine.  From what I understand, this is a runtime classpath issue.

The error is shown here:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class
>   Controllers.LoginServlet
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Model/Converter
>     db.UserHelper.(UserHelper.java:34)
>     Controllers.LoginServlet.(LoginServlet.java:36)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Model.Converter
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
>     db.UserHelper.(UserHelper.java:34)
>     Controllers.LoginServlet.(LoginServlet.java:36)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Here's a screenshot of my folder structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZoV9.jpg

src/Controllers and src/Model were the packages I switched to lower case.  I switched them back hoping to resolve the issue, but to no avail.

I tried checking my runtime classpath for the project by going to Run --> Run Configurations, but the project isn't listed there.

Here is a snapshot of my Web Deployment Assembly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0fL4.jpg

Does anyone know how I might go about fixing this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***Solution Found***

Thanks for responses everyone.  Thankfully I managed to fix the issue by:

1. Right clicking the project folder ---> Build Path ---> Configure Build Path
2. Navigating to Source tab
3. I saw that the default output folder was "WorkTicketSystem/build/classes."  I switched this to "WorkTicketSystem/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes."

And, voila.  I'm not exactly sure why or how my actions fixed the problem, but if anyone could explain I would be very interested to hear it. For now I am just happy that it runs.

Comment: let me guess. windows?

Comment: Most of the similar problems I had with Eclipse, were due to how it published the resources, and it was usually solved by right clicking the configured server in the "Servers" view, and selecting "Clean"

Comment: Could you post the contents of your web.xml file? I suspect you have a fully qualified class name in there referring to your old package name.

Comment: I actually don't have a web.xml file for this project.  I edited my post to show how I managed to get around the issue.  Thank you for the response!

Comment: Uh, the error says that class "Model.Converter" cannot be found.  That means that somewhere you're referencing "Model.Converter" instead of "model.Converter".

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml, you have a reference to the class Model.Converter. You need to change this to model.Converter.

Answer (score 0):

If we change the package name to uppercase we have to check whether all references with that package got modified or not. As you are saying that if you try to run package names with lower case is working fine. If you try to modify the package names with IDE that will ask for updating references also. Once check that.

**NOTE:** **As per java coding standards package names should be in lower case.**